# Making jquery plugin for some HTML elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I want to create a jquery plugin and use that for some HTML elements in my page.
This is my HTML code :

```
<select class="test">
    <option>
        111
    </option>
    <option>
        222
    </option>
    <option>
        333
    </option>
</select>
<select class="test">
    <option>
        444
    </option>
    <option>
        555
    </option>
</select>
```

I want to use my plugin for `select` elements.
This is my plugin sample :

```
(function ( $ ) {
        $.fn.testplug = function() {
            var res = "";
            this.children("option").each(function(){
                res+=$(this).text()+"#";
            });
            alert(res);
        };
    }( jQuery ));
```

And for using it :

```
$(".test").testplug();
```

Now i aspect to have two `res` values,one of them should be `111#222#333#` and another should be `444#555#`, but i have one result and it's `111#222#333#444#555#`.
What should i do for getting my desired result?
[Link to jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uEEJZ/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are selecting both so you must specify which one you want to use

```
$('.test:first').testplug() //111#222#333
```

and

```
$('.test:last').testplug() //444#555#
```

or

```
$('select').on('change',function(){
    $(this).testplug();
});
```

or you could loop through every .test like this

```
$('.test').each(function(){
$(this).testplug();
});
```

You can also rewrite the code like this, to loop through the lists then children and alert at the end of every list

```
 (function ( $ ) {
        $.fn.testplug = function() {
            this.each(function(){
                  var res = "";
                $(this).children('option').each(function(){
                          res+=$(this).text()+"#";
                });
                 alert(res);
            });
        };
    }( jQuery ));
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/uEEJZ/4/)

Comment: Yes, it's working but i have more than 2 select elements,also i don't want to using 'change' event.

Comment: Check update @SamanGholami if you want to use your original code you can do this 
`$('.test').each(function(){
$(this).testplug();
});`

Answer (score 1):

You mean 2 alert on one called plugin function ?

```
   $.fn.testplug = function() {
        $(this).each(function(){
           var res = "";
           $(this).children("option").each(function(){
              res+=$(this).text()+"#";
           });
           alert(res);
        });
    };
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply :)
You should put res in loop